# Math calculation for two lists

Tags: c#, list, winforms

I have two Lists (CalculateDensityPorosity() and Neuton) and I wanna do Math calculation for each element of this lists; I am in a class so I cannot use "foreach"

the code that I tried is:

```
public static List<double> CalculateNDPorosity() =>
CalculateDensityPorosity().Select(PhiD => Neutron.Select(PhiN=> (Math.Pow(PhiD, 2)+ Math.Pow(PhiN, 2))/2)).ToList();
```

Comment: `I am in a class so I cannot use "foreach"` Why not? `the code that I tried is:` What is the problem and what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: 'Invalid token "foreach" in a class' is the error when I try to use foreach

Comment: Can you share the code which uses `foreach`? What problem you are facing with the code you have shared?

Comment: If you use `{ }` rather than `=>` then you can use whatever code you'd like, including a `foreach`.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected results for those sample inputs**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example:

```
public static List<double> CalculateNDPorosity() => ...
```

is an "[expression bodied member](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/01/25/expressionbodiedmembers/)", that means that the "..." must be an expression. A `foreach` is a statement (not an expression), so a full body needs to be used:

```
public static List<double> CalculateNDPorosity()
{
    foreach (...)
    {
        ...
    }

    return ...;
}
```